# printing a barcode image from a webpage on to a label reducing size when printing

Tags: php, barcode-scanner, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

We have created a barcode image with size 380 width and 120 height.It is fine when display on a web page.Barcode scanner also scanning fine.

when printed on a A4 desktop printer which prints minimum 300 dpi,the a4 barcode scans fine.But when I tried to print the entire web page with bar code image on a label the information printing will be reducing by browser to fit on to a label.

The barcode is becoming much smaller on label and not able to scan it.Is there nay way to print it on the 200 dpi zebra label printer.Please suggest any idea.do we need to do any print settings?or increase the size of the barcode image to print on 200 dpi label printer?

Comment: Is the shrinking of the barcode image itself causing the distortion of the barcode? What software are you using to generate the barcode image?

Comment: yes,iam using code128 for generating barcode,using php

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to insist on generating the barcode yourself, you need to map the resolution of the image to the resolution of the printer. However, Zebra printers are designed to print barcodes given simply the data to encode. I suggest you rely on the printer's API, which is guaranteed by the vendor to work. You can ask your salesman for support, too.

Comment: I have to agree with John. If the target output for your barcode is the Zebra printer, you should be using ZPL. The firmware in the printer is capable of rendering the barcode in a legible manner, and you should not try to create a bitmap in the computer's memory and download that. Are you needing to generate a barcode for both A4 and Zebra?